# Elixir io_lib call to erlang

Tags: erlang, erl, elixir

```
io_lib:fread("~d/~d/~d", "2013/03/03").
```

Above code works in erlang so ideally in elixir below code should work

```
:io_lib.fread("~d/~d/~d", "2013/03/03")
```

but it generates error " no function clause matching "

After inspecting found that elixir makes call to module like

```
:io_lib_fread.fread("~d/~d/~d", "2013/03/03", 0, [])
```

Comment: Have you checked whether it's a macro expansion?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A double quote in erlang `"char list"` translates to single quotes in Elixir `'char list'`.

Comment: Thanks Jose !!! works perfectly.. didnt expected a reply from creator or Elixir.. its such a great language.. :)