# Elixir calling :io_lib.fread

Tags: erlang, elixir

How do you properly get a character list into Erlang from Elixir?

Suppose I do this is Erlang:

```
12> [X,Y | R] = "54686973206973206120746573742e".
"54686973206973206120746573742e"

13> X.
53

14> Y.
52

15> io_lib:fread("~16u",[53,52]).                
{ok,"T",[]}
```

How do make that call correctly from Elixir?

```
:io_lib.fread("~16u",...)
```

I have already seen this question:
[Elixir io_lib call to erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756293/elixir-io-lib-call-to-erlang)

But I still seem to get a FunctionClauseError no matter what approach I take to push the list into fread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using single quotes around the format string as described in the linked question seems to work:

```
iex(1)> :io_lib.fread('~16u', [53,52])
{:ok, 'T', []}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was totally focused on the wrong parameter.  The key is the format parameter needs to be an Elixir character list.